# Autocomplete based on list value - not string

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I'm trying to use your AutoComplete project to populate list values based on an identifier

1 - User populates PropertyID
2 - PropertyName and Property Address get autoPopulated from the master Property list

What would the REST Filter look like ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How does user populates the PropertyID? By typing to a textbox?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not good in jquery, but the general idea is:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18160342/jquery-how-to-trigger-click-event-on-pressing-enter-key

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj860569(v=office.15).aspx

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $("#txtSearchProdAssign").keyup(function (e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    var PropertyID = $("#txtSearchProdAssign").val();
    fillpup(PropertyID);
  }

} 
});

fillup( fillpup(PropertyID)) {

$.ajax( {
                url:"http://dev/_api/Lists(guid'D42378B2-CD5A-4AF8-B6BD-47048B84D642')/items?&$filter=PropertyID eq '" + PropertyID+"'&$select=propertyname,propertyAddress",
                type:"GET",
                 headers: {
                    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                },
                success: function(data){ 
                $('#propertyname').val (data.d.results[0].propertyname);
                $('#propertyAddress').val (data.d.results[0].propertyAddress);

            }//success
                ,
                error: function(error){
                                    //llog(" Error:" + mythis.val());
                console.log(" Ajax error:" + JSON.stringify(error));
                        }//error
                });//ajax
}
```